# trying to populate a single field in each object inside an array of objects by dynamically picking the model to use with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, schema, mongoose-populate

I'm trying to use refPath to reference which collection to pull the population data from inside my schema, and even though it looks identical to the examples I've seen, its just not working.

Here is my schema for statesPersons, not super important, but it contains the activeWork array of objects.

```
import mongoose, {model, Schema}  from "mongoose";

const statesPersonsSchema = new Schema(
  {
    profileId: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    department: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      index: true,
    },
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    location: String,
    org: String,
    title: String,
    jobDescription: String,
    email: {
      type: String,
      lowercase: true,
    },
    phoneNumber: String,
    activeWork: ["activeWork"],
    emailList: [String],
    jobAssignments: [String],
    affiantInfo: {
      affiantInfoTitle: String,
      affiantInfoExperience: String,
    },
    assessments: [
      {
        assessdBy: {
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "statesPerson",
        },
        dueDate: Date,
        questions: {},
      },
    ],
  },
  { strictPopulate: false }
);



export default mongoose.model("statesPersons", statesPersonsSchema);
```

Here is my schema for activeWork, the array of objects. This has the referenceId that I need to populate as well as the collectionType which I pull what collection it is from.

```
import mongoose, {model, Schema}  from "mongoose";

const activeWorkSchema = new Schema(
  {
    active: Boolean,
    collectionType: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["messages", "cases"],
    },
    referenceId: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      refPath: "collectionType",
    },
    sentBy: {
      type: Schema.Types.String,
      ref: "statesPersons",
    },
    sentTo: {
      type: Schema.Types.String,
      ref: "statesPersons",
    },
    timeRecived: Date,
    dueDate: Date,
    subject: String,
    viewed: Boolean,
    content: {},
  },
  { strictPopulate: false }
);

  export default mongoose.model("activeWork", activeWorkSchema);
```

And here is my query.

```
export async function getStatesPersonsActiveWorkByProfileId(req, res){
    mongoose.set('debug', true);
    try{
        const { profileId } = req.params

        const data = await statesPersons
        .find({ profileId })
        .populate('statesPersons.activeWork.referenceId')
        .exec()
        
        return res.send({
            message: "success",
             data: data,
             status: 200 })
    }catch(e) {
        console.error(e.message)
        return res.send({
            message: "couldn't fetch active work",
             data: null,
             status: 500 })
    }
}
```

its returning with the statesPersons object and the activeWork contains the objectId I need to populate, but its not populating. it looks like this.

```
"activeWork": [
                {
                    "active": true,
                    "collectionType": "messages",
                    "referenceId": "63a49e3052658ce60c1dafcb",
                    "sentBy": "108416469928574003772",
                    "dueDate": "2018-02-21T11:16:50.362Z",
                    "subject": "testing",
                    "viewed": false,
                    "_id": "63a49e3052658ce60c1dafce"
```

I can force it to work by changing the query to be explicit.

```
        const data = await statesPersons
        .find({ profileId })
        .populate({path: 'activeWork.referenceId', model: 'messages'})
        .exec()
```

which looks like this.

```
activeWork": [
            {
                    "active": true,
                    "collectionType": "messages",
                    "referenceId": {
                        "_id": "63a49e3052658ce60c1dafcb",
                        "involvedParties": [
                            "108416469928574003772",
                            "100335565301468600000"
                        ],
                        "comments": [
                            {
                                "sender": [
                                    "108416469928574003772"
                                ],
                                "dateSent": "2022-12-22T18:13:04.604Z",
                                "content": "There is no way this is going to work.",
                                "_id": "63a49e3052658ce60c1dafcc"
                            }
                        ],
```

But this wont work because I need it to be able to pull what model to use from the collectionType field

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the late response , it seems like you are trying to populate the multilevel documents [multilevel population](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#deep-populate).

here is an example.

```
db.statesPersonsSchema.find({ profileId }). populate({
    path: 'activeWorkSchema',
    populate: { path: 'referenceId' }
  });
```